# .exe file permission fail

Tags: wine, permissions, ntfs

I'm trying to run a exe file that is located on my Vista partition, when I browse to the file and try to change the file to run as executable the tick box unticks itself right after i tick it, i tried running gksu nautilus but it does the same thing

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is likely because the Vista partition is using the NTFS filesystem and it was mounted with an `fmask` that does not permit setting execute permissions on files.

To fix this you need to manually mount the partition.

Details can be found on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-to-chmod-on-an-ntfs-partition/11843#11843) post.

---

Here are the steps you need to take:

1. Determine the drive's corresponding device by opening a terminal and typing: `df`
2. The column on the far left is the device, and the column on the far right is the path for the drive. Find the device for the Vista partition.
3. Unmount the Windows partition. (Click the eject button [image] that's next to it in Nautilus)
4. Open a terminal
5. Type the following:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /media/vista
   sudo mount -t ntfs -o fmask=0022,dmask=0000,uid=1000,gid=1000 \
       <DRIVE> /media/vista
   ```

   Replace `<DRIVE>` with your drive's device.

Comment: ive never had this problem before doing the same thing though, and that post is WAY too technical for me lol

Comment: @Zabadda: I added more clear instructions. Does that help?

Comment: ok df gives me this http://paste.ubuntu.com/545368/

Comment: @Zabadda: Assuming you had it mounted at that point, your Vista device is `/dev/sda1`.

Comment: so is this what i need? sudo mount -t ntfs -o fmask=0022,dmask=0000,uid=1000,gid=1000 /dev/sda1/media/vista

Comment: @Zabadda: Not quite. You need a space in there: `sudo mount -t ntfs -o fmask=0022,dmask=0000,uid=1000,gid=1000 /dev/sda1 /media/vista`

Comment: I'm also assuming your user ID is 1000. (I think that's the default.)

Comment: Your sir are a genius! no idea what we jost done to make that work but it does! will that always work now or do i have to mount it that way each time?

Comment: @Zabadda: The way it is now, you'll have to do that every time. But there is a way to do it so that it will always mount that way. That would probably be better as a second question though, as it involves some other work.

Comment: well what shall I ask for a question so you can answer it and get the credit :P

Comment: @Zabadda: Maybe something similar to "How to add NTFS partition to fstab?" and then explain that you want the partition to automatically mount with certain parameters, etc.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18067/how-to-add-ntfs-partition-to-fstab

Answer (score 2):

when using 10.04 running wine's .exes from a windows terminal worked alright, but now on 10.10 it just doesn't. I think it is a new security feature. Instead of running it from a windows partition transfer the files to your ubuntu filesystem, and run it from there. Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

One other workaround is to enable the Wine PPA, since it disables the execute bit checking that the normal Ubuntu packages do.