# Why does Ubuntu refuse to execute files from an NTFS partition?

Tags: filesystem, permissions, ntfs, fstab, executable

I mount an NTFS partition (where I've got some Linux binaries and scripts alongside with Win32 and data files) with the following fstab line:

```
/dev/sda5 /mnt/dat ntfs-3g rw,dev,exec,auto,async,users,umask=000,uid=1000,gid=1000,locale=en_US.utf8,  errors=remount-ro 0 0
```

All files seem to have executable attribute set then, but if I try to actually execute them, I get "Permission denied" error. Even with sudo. Even while execute (as well as read and write) permissions are granted to everyone and all the files owner is set to the user.

So how do I set the system up to be able to run Linux binaries from NTFS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.exe file permission fail](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18052/exe-file-permission-fail)

Comment: Hardly even related to ".exe file permission fail" question. I have no problems with .exe files. The question is NOT about running Windows executables on Linux, it is about running Linux executables located on a Windows partition.

Comment: if you read this carefully - you will see that it is related. Or maybe you don't understand how linux sees executables. The extension doesn't make the difference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to 'chmod' on an NTFS ( or FAT32 ) partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-to-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition)

Comment: try using fmask=0022,dmask=0000 instead of umask

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same problem and the solution in my case was to write de `exec` mount option **after** the `users` option. That's because the `users` option implicitly activate the `noexec` option, so you have to explicitly specify `exec`.

I got this from ["Why can't I run programs on another partition in Linux?" on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29089/why-cant-i-run-programs-on-another-partition-in-linux).

Comment: Exactly right -- "users" sets noexec, so "users,exec" should be used, in that order.

Answer (score 2):

There were a few people mulling this one over in the chat channels.  One of the people suggested that you take a look at George Edison's response to this question, and see if it helps you:
 
[.exe file permission fail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18052/exe-file-permission-fail/18053#18053)

Note that you will have to have additional mount options on an NTFS partition in order to execute binary files from those partitions directly - the `users` option, and also the `exec` option.  `users` permits unmounting by non-superusers (as well as mounting), and `exec` permits executables to be run from it (however, keep in mind this isn't a guarantee to make everything work).

Comment: I have no problems with .exe files. The question is NOT about running Windows executables on Linux, it is about running Linux executables located on a Windows partition.

Comment: sigh... please read it carefully.

Answer (score 1):

That is the "feature" of udisks package to, by default, restricts permission modification on ntfs partition (or other non-Linux partitions).

To enable this feature, you may want to read,

[Enable Setting Executable Permission of Files at NTFS Partition](http://hilfan.staff.telkomuniversity.ac.id/2012/08/05/enable-setting-executable-permission-of-files-at-ntfs-partition/)

Comment: Also related: [NTFS-3G: File Ownership and Permissions](http://b.andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/permissions.html)

Comment: The link in this answer is dead :(