# How to get permissions to execute programs from NTFS hard drive?

Tags: permissions, ntfs, fstab, automount

I have this problem: I'm used to compile and run `.c` files with CodeBlocks. If I do that from my Desktop (`ext4` partition) it works without problems, but doing this from my secondary hard drive (`NTFS` partition) makes CodeBlocks to say `permission denied` while running a `.c` file.

I have read it's because of the partition type is it correct? But I don't know how to solve it.
I tried to edit `fstab` (`sudo gedit /etc/fstab`) adding this line:

```
/dev/sda /media/Dati ntfs user,exec 0 1
```

but after rebooting Ubuntu I had a warning on boot about `a problem mounting a drive`, that's because I set KDE to auto mount my `Dati` drive on boot.

So I should auto mount my NTFS drive with execute permission? How can I do that?

Comment: You can read but not write the file, Am I right?

Comment: I can read it but I can't execute it I think and I can't write as well. I can't also set permissions nor from dolphin with the "sudo" option

Comment: Well, that means that you only have `read` permissions over that partition. That partition is from the same HDD that Ubuntu or is an external drive?

Comment: Have you reviewed [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/30243/62483)?

Comment: I have just solved it, I have posted the answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Follow these steps to make a NTFS partition executable:

1. Open a terminal and type `sudo blkid -c /dev/null`
   This command allow you to identify your `NTFS` drive and your [`UUID`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) number. *Example*:

   ```
   /dev/sdb1: LABEL="my_label" UUID="xxx" TYPE="ntfs"
   ```
2. Open the `/etc/fstab` file from terminal typing `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab`
3. Don’t edit the existing lines, but add new one at the end like this example:

   ```
   UUID=xxx /media/my_label ntfs-3g defaults,auto,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=002 0 0
   ```

   **NOTE:** Replace the `UUID` number and the **mounting point** `/media/my_label` according to your situation!
4. Save the file and close the text editor.
5. Enter the next command in the terminal: `sudo mount -a`
6. And restart Ubuntu. Done

Now, every time you mount your `NTFS` partition, you will be able to run executable files.

Comment: Please tell us if **that partition is of the same HDD that Ubuntu or is of an external drive?**

Comment: it's an external drive

Comment: I can't change files' permissions after making this change, even if I add `users,permissions` after `defaults,auto`. My line is currently like this: `/dev/sdb4 /path/to/mount ntfs-3g defaults,auto,users,permissions,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=002   0   0` Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I tried above solutions but didn’t work for me. This worked.

`UUID=xxx /media/ny ntfs-3g    auto,users,permissions,exec,big_writes,windows_names 0       0`

Ref - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NTFS-3G