# Permission denied when running C programs outside the Home directory

Tags: permissions, compiling, c, executable

I have been creating some C programs and I have saved them to my Home directory while editing. I have compiled them with gcc and then run the executable file with `./` and they work fine. However, when the programs are ready, I take the executables to another directory in another partition of my hard drive where I store my personal files, but when I try to run them from this new location, the terminal prompts the message "Permission denied".

Is there any way that I can run the programs from any location I store them, other than the Home directory?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get permissions to compile a C program from NTFS hard drive?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/245154/how-to-get-permissions-to-compile-a-c-program-from-ntfs-hard-drive) or http://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-to-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition

Comment: The solution given in the link provided above for the duplicated of this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/245154/how-to-get-permissions-to-compile-a-c-program-from-ntfs-hard-drive, solved the issue.