# Permission denied when trying to open a file in gimp

Tags: permissions

When I try to open a .psd file using gimp I get this error:

```
Opening '/media/anonoymous/Other's/Practise/bootstarp/design.psd' failed: Could not open '/media/anonoymous/Other's/Practise/bootstarp/design.psd' for reading: Permission denied
```

What should I do?

Comment: Please add the output of the command `ls -l /media/anonoymous/Other\'s/Practise/bootstarp/design.psd` to your question. Also, check if the path is valid, it contains multiple misspelled English words.

Comment: Is the file on an NTFS (Windows) partition? Please also give the output of `mount`

Comment: You should try to add this file as sudo, it looks like you have it mounted in a shared drive with windows... Usually this kind of mounting have all files with owner and group as `root`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get permissions to execute programs from NTFS hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245154/how-to-get-permissions-to-execute-programs-from-ntfs-hard-drive)

Answer (score 59):

I was able to correct this error by giving the gimp snap access to the removable-media plug by entering the following command:

```
snap connect gimp:removable-media :removable-media
```

Best of Luck

Comment: I needed sudo to run this command.

Comment: thanks, this work for me.

Answer (score 50):

The Ubuntu Software program now has a way to set permissions on the page for the snap software with this issue. There is a 'Permissions' button under the name of the program.

[image: The page for GIMP in the Ubuntu Software program, showing the Launch, Remove, and Permissions buttons]

Click that, and then click the button next to where it says 'Read/write files on removable storage devices'

[image]

You will be prompted to enter your password. After that the problem is solved.

Ubuntu will regard internal drives other than the drive with the Ubuntu OS as removable storage devices too.

Comment: this should be accepted

Comment: Thanks that worked like a charm and helped me out quite a bit!

Comment: This worked for me - permission to access removable drives was turned off

Comment: Thank you! For the longest time I have been mystified about why my applications cannot see my network drive but I can see it just fine from the shell or file manager. GIMP gave me a clue with an error, but others just fail silently. The GIMP error led me here. Problem now solved.

Answer (score 3):

Gimp wouldn't open any files for me, even when I fixed the permissions. I deinstalled the snap version, and reinstalled with

sudo apt install gimp

and the problems went away.

Comment: This will only circuvent the problem. The problem ist the permissions of the snap package: when installing with apt you will have two separate gimp-installations. One as snap and one as deb.
See @andrew s solution

Answer (score 1):

I had an analogous problem but with .pat file. My problem was actually that the owner and the group of the file (check it by using the command `ls -la`) was set to `root` for some reason. I changed it with `chwon myuser:mygroup myfile` to the local user and the problem was solved.

Good luck.