# Missing executable permissions on secondary internal disk

Tags: command-line, permissions, kde, 21.10

I've just installed Ubuntu Studio after migrating from Manjaro, and every time I run Android Studio (which is installed in my secondary drive, which is mounted in `~/Storage`) I get the following error:

```
The program '/home/myms/Storage/04 ANDROID STUDIO/android-studio/bin/studio.sh' is missing executable permissions.
```

[image]

This happens with every execution command from this drive.
I tried `sudo chmod a+rwx ~/Storage` but that made no difference, I know it's about the file being executable, I already checked that.

The read and write permissions work fine, it's just the execution permissions.

The output of `ls -l '/home/myms/../studio.sh'`

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myms myms 6603 Sep  7 17:55 '/home/myms/Storage/04 ANDROID STUDIO/android-studio/bin/studio.sh'
```

The output of `sudo blkid -c /dev/null`:

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: LABEL_FATBOOT="NO_LABEL" LABEL="NO_LABEL" UUID="9506-4F7D" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="7e565882-2596-8e4e-81db-46a214695139"
/dev/sda2: UUID="726a12dd-9d6a-4cdb-9186-ac454f33546f" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="root" PARTUUID="ca46cde7-fb4e-1648-a88e-30701ba0489d"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Storage" UUID="efc6bf95-a436-4d02-b544-6f9ca414ae9f" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="5d5db06e-01"
```

The output of `ls -l`:

```
...
drwxrwxrwx 14 myms myms     4096 Oct 23 18:32 Storage
...
```

The output of `./pathlld /dev/sdb1`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root 4096 Oct 24 09:04 /
/dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard)
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4640 Oct 25 07:25 /dev
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=3980132k,nr_inodes=995033,mode=755,inode64)
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 17 Oct 25 07:25 /dev/sdb1
```

**System info summary:**

- **Distro**: Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish Indri)
- **Kernel**: 5.13.0-20-lowlatency x86_64
- **Desktop**: KDE Plasma 5.22.5

The output of the `inxi -Fazy` command:

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.13.0-20-lowlatency x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.2.0 
  parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-20-lowlatency 
  root=UUID=726a12dd-9d6a-4cdb-9186-ac454f33546f ro threadirqs quiet splash 
  vt.handoff=1 
  Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.22.5 tk: Qt 5.15.2 wm: kwin_x11 vt: 1 dm: SDDM 
  Distro: Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish Indri) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 80TU v: Lenovo ideapad 310-14IKB 
  serial: <filter> Chassis: type: 10 v: Lenovo ideapad 310-14IKB 
  serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: LENOVO model: Torronto 4C2 v: NO DPK serial: <filter> UEFI: LENOVO 
  v: 3JCN21WW date: 09/23/2016 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 21.0 Wh (100.0%) condition: 21.0/30.0 Wh (70.1%) 
  volts: 8.5 min: 7.4 model: SMP L15M2PB2 type: Li-poly serial: <filter> 
  status: Full 
CPU:
  Info: Dual Core model: Intel Core i7-7500U bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  arch: Amber/Kaby Lake note: check family: 6 model-id: 8E (142) stepping: 9 
  microcode: EA cache: L2: 4 MiB 
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx 
  bogomips: 23199 
  Speed: 600 MHz min/max: 400/3500 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 600 2: 618 3: 700 
  4: 623 
  Vulnerabilities: Type: itlb_multihit status: KVM: VMX disabled 
  Type: l1tf 
  mitigation: PTE Inversion; VMX: conditional cache flushes, SMT vulnerable 
  Type: mds mitigation: Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable 
  Type: meltdown mitigation: PTI 
  Type: spec_store_bypass 
  mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp 
  Type: spectre_v1 
  mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization 
  Type: spectre_v2 mitigation: Full generic retpoline, IBPB: conditional, 
  IBRS_FW, STIBP: conditional, RSB filling 
  Type: srbds mitigation: Microcode 
  Type: tsx_async_abort status: Not affected 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 620 vendor: Lenovo driver: i915 v: kernel 
  bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:5916 class-ID: 0300 
  Device-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 920MX] vendor: Lenovo driver: nvidia 
  v: 470.74 alternate: nvidiafb,nouveau,nvidia_drm bus-ID: 03:00.0 
  chip-ID: 10de:134f class-ID: 0302 
  Device-3: Chicony EasyCamera type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 1-4:4 
  chip-ID: 04f2:b57d class-ID: 0e02 serial: <filter> 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 compositor: kwin_x11 driver: 
  loaded: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa display-ID: :0 
  screens: 1 
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 3286x1080 s-dpi: 96 s-size: 867x285mm (34.1x11.2") 
  s-diag: 913mm (35.9") 
  Monitor-1: eDP-1 res: 1366x768 hz: 60 dpi: 112 size: 309x173mm (12.2x6.8") 
  diag: 354mm (13.9") 
  Monitor-2: DP-1 res: 1920x1080 hz: 60 dpi: 36 size: 1360x768mm (53.5x30.2") 
  diag: 1562mm (61.5") 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.2 
  direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio vendor: Lenovo 
  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel alternate: snd_soc_skl bus-ID: 00:1f.3 
  chip-ID: 8086:9d71 class-ID: 0403 
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.13.0-20-lowlatency running: yes 
  Sound Server-2: JACK v: 1.9.19 running: no 
  Sound Server-3: PulseAudio v: 15.0 running: yes 
  Sound Server-4: PipeWire v: 0.3.32 running: yes 
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
  vendor: Lenovo driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 4000 bus-ID: 01:00.0 
  chip-ID: 10ec:8168 class-ID: 0200 
  IF: enp1s0 state: down mac: <filter> 
  Device-2: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter 
  vendor: Lenovo driver: ath10k_pci v: kernel port: 4000 bus-ID: 02:00.0 
  chip-ID: 168c:0042 class-ID: 0280 
  IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Qualcomm Atheros type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus-ID: 1-7:6 
  chip-ID: 0cf3:e500 class-ID: e001 
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 2 state: down bt-service: enabled,running 
  rfk-block: hardware: no software: yes address: <filter> 
  Info: acl-mtu: 1024:8 sco-mtu: 50:8 link-policy: rswitch hold sniff 
  link-mode: slave accept 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 372.62 GiB used: 243.56 GiB (65.4%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda maj-min: 8:0 vendor: Kingston model: SA400S37240G 
  size: 223.57 GiB block-size: physical: 512 B logical: 512 B speed: 6.0 Gb/s 
  type: SSD serial: <filter> rev: 0102 scheme: GPT 
  SMART Message: Unknown smartctl error. Unable to generate data. 
  ID-2: /dev/sdb maj-min: 8:16 vendor: Seagate model: ST9160412AS 
  size: 149.05 GiB block-size: physical: 512 B logical: 512 B speed: 3.0 Gb/s 
  type: HDD rpm: 7200 serial: <filter> rev: HPM1 scheme: MBR 
  SMART Message: Unknown smartctl error. Unable to generate data. 
Partition:
  ID-1: / raw-size: 223.27 GiB size: 218.71 GiB (97.96%) 
  used: 145.27 GiB (66.4%) fs: ext4 block-size: 4096 B dev: /dev/sda2 
  maj-min: 8:2 
  ID-2: /boot/efi raw-size: 300 MiB size: 299.4 MiB (99.80%) 
  used: 5.9 MiB (2.0%) fs: vfat block-size: 512 B dev: /dev/sda1 maj-min: 8:1
```

Comment: Is your second drive formatted in NTFS? https://askubuntu.com/questions/245154/how-to-get-permissions-to-execute-programs-from-ntfs-hard-drive

Comment: No, ext4. But thanks for replying @Mark

Comment: Add the output of `ls -l '/home/myms/Storage/04 ANDROID STUDIO/android-studio/bin/studio.sh'` to your answer.

Comment: You can try with : sudo chmod -Rf 777 /dev/sdb1

Comment: Thanks @kyodake, but it didn't work unfortunately. Wait a minute, do I need to reboot or unmount and mount after running a `chmod` command?

Comment: @YoungFellow do not blindly follow random recommendations of commands, especially commands preceded by `sudo`, except if you like to reinstall your system now and then.

Comment: Could the 2nd drive be mounted with the `noexec` option? Look at `mount`. Read `man mount`. Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`, a `bash` script.

Comment: Okay, so running `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /home/myms/Storage --rw` worked for me, but how do I make sure I don't have to keep doing this every time I log in?

Comment: Add a proper entry in etc fstab

Comment: And how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve the problem by setting the drive's line in `fstab` to:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/efc6bf95-a436-4d02-b544-6f9ca414ae9f /home/myms/Storage auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Thanks to @waltinator for telling me to do some reading ;)