# Unable to make files executable (on ntfs filesystem mounted as rw)

Tags: mount, permissions, ntfs, chmod

I'm baffled. I've looked around for awhile on this but nobody seems to have quite the issue I do.

I have an ntfs partition for all of my stuff, and I want to run some programs off of it. However, I keep getting `Permission denied.`

Very well, I'll try `sudo ./eclipse`. Nope.

Okay, well, maybe I have to chmod. `sudo chmod +x eclipse`.
No error. `ls -l`. `eclipse` is still `-rw-------`. What?

Verbose output! `sudo chmod -v +x eclipse`
Result: `mode of 'eclipse' changed from 0600 (rw-------) to 0711 (rwx--x--x)`
Yay! Nope, `ls -l` reveals that it's still `-rw-------`.

I then open nautilus as root, and find the file, and try to do it from the GUI. Turns out the same thing happens. The "Allow executing file as program" option isn't disabled, but when I tick the box it unticks the moment my mouse leaves. What's going on?

`mount` reveals that this partition is mounted in `rw` mode, which I know is important.

---

fstab line is

```
UUID="755AF93248ACABD6" /s ntfs rw,auto,users,nls=utf8,umask=007,gid=46 0 0
```

Comment: show us fstab line for this disc... option `noexec` would be my guess ;-)

Comment: hmm, yeah this ( http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1787053 ) suggests it's something like that. hangon and let me restart to check

Comment: nope, fstab line is `UUID="755AF93248ACABD6" /s                                ntfs    rw,auto,users,nls=utf8,umask=007,gid=46        0       0`

Comment: You're having this problem? http://askubuntu.com/questions/30243/why-does-ubuntu-refuse-to-execute-files-from-an-ntfs-partition

Comment: Okay, so sure, if I follow the instructions and run `sudo mount -t ntfs -o fmask=0022,dmask=0000,uid=1000,gid=1000 /dev/sda7 /media/testmount` then it works. But how do I fix this in fstab?

Comment: I don't want to have to mount manually every time

Comment: -o just means mount options, so you put those options in the fstab option field...

Answer (score 3):

With "ntfs permissions are set at the time of mounting the partition with umask, dmask, and fmask and can not be changed with commands such as chown or chmod."[source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab)

Try changing `umask=007` to `dmask=027,fmask=037`