# Cannot install app from non home directory

Tags: command-line

I moved netbeans-7.4-linux.sh in the following directory 
`/media/hosam/I/Linux`, before installing Ubuntu. What I type:

```
hosam@HOSAM:~$ cd '/media/hosam/I/Linux/'
hosam@HOSAM:/media/hosam/I/Linux$ sudo chmod +x netbeans-7.4-linux.sh
[sudo] password for hosam: 
hosam@HOSAM:/media/hosam/I/Linux$ sudo ./netbeans-7.4-linux.sh
```

What I get

`sudo: ./netbeans-7.4-linux.sh: command not found`

When I moved it to `/home` it worked well

Answer (score 2):

`./` means "this directory". If you've moved it somewhere else you either need to change directory with `cd`:

```
cd /media/hosam/I/Linux
./netbeans-7.4-linux.sh
```

Or give the full path when calling it:

```
/media/hosam/I/Linuxnetbeans-7.4-linux.sh
```

---

You'll also need to make sure it has been marked executable. You can do this through the right click properties menu in Nautilus or by running

```
chmod +x /media/hosam/I/Linuxnetbeans-7.4-linux.sh
```

If that still doesn't work, it seems likely that the filesystem it's sitting on is probably mounted in such a way that prevents files being directly executed. That leaves you with a few options:

- Call `sh /media/hosam/I/Linuxnetbeans-7.4-linux.sh` explicitly (this doesn't need execute permissions)
- Remount the `/media/hosam/` filesystem as executable. If it's NTFS, [see this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281484/unable-to-make-files-executable-on-ntfs-filesystem-mounted-as-rw)
- Or move the file to a filesystem that will support it being `chmod +x`

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the script file into the `/` directory, so that the script will execute or otherwise it won't execute by default.

It needs some workaround to execute a script which was actually present inside an ntfs partition.Just try to remount the ntfs partition by following [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/11843/202806) answer, so that you can be able to chmod the files inside ntfs partition.

```
sudo mkdir /media/foo
sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,user,fmask=0022,dmask=0000 /dev/whatever /media/foo
sudo chmod +x /path/netbeans-7.4-linux.sh
sh /path/netbeans-7.4-linux.sh
```