# Lost Steam games stored in NTFS partition upon upgrading to 13.04; can't re-add Steam Library Folder

Tags: ntfs, fstab, steam

I used a Live DVD to upgrade to 13.04. However, this reset my fstab file, which I had previously set up to auto-mount using pysdm. Because of this, when I reinstalled Steam, it was unable to detect the games I had previously installed to my Windows partition. Attempting to re-add this folder to my Steam Library Folders left me with an error message stating

> New Steam library folder must be on a filesystem with executable
>   permissions.

I then edited my fstab file to add the appropriate partition with the options `uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137`, but I still get this error. How do I re-add my old Steam Library Folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also have Steam libraries on an NTFS partition, on Ubuntu 13.04, here is the fstab entry for that partition (I removed the rest):

```
# <file system>         <mount point>      <type>   <options>       <dump>  <pass>
...
...
...
#add execution right on data partition
UUID=50B06A2EB06A1B2C /media/etienne/data   auto    auto,exec         0       0
```

You probably need exactly the same options except for the partition's UUID, to get the UUID of your partition, locate your partion in /dev and use blkid, for an example if your partition is /dev/sda1 use: `sudo blkid /dev/sda1` You will get a result like this:

```
etienne@etienne-laptop:~$ sudo blkid /dev/sda7
/dev/sda7: LABEL="data" UUID="50B06A2EB06A1B2C" TYPE="ntfs"
```

If it still doesn't work it means you need to add other mount options, in this case have a look at [that question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30243/why-does-ubuntu-refuse-to-execute-files-from-an-ntfs-partition?rq=1).