# Steam not letting me make new folders

Tags: fstab, steam

I'm trying to make a folder on my data drive for my steam games and I keep getting this

"New Steam library must be on a file system mounted with execute permissions"

Answer (score 0):

It's just like Steam says: the drive has to have executable permissions. You can edit your fstab file or use the disk utility to handle that for you. Examples can be found in [previous questions asked here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287018/lost-steam-games-stored-in-ntfs-partition-upon-upgrading-to-13-04-cant-re-add).