# Can't execute files in windows partitions from Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, ntfs

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 inside Windows.  I can't execute files in my Windows NTFS partitions. It gives the following error:

```
root@ubuntu:/media/rakesh/Data/My Codes/Test# ./a.out 
bash: ./a.out : Permission denied
```

I have tried solutions in the following threads but it does not work:

- [How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition)
- [Why does Ubuntu refuse to execute files from an NTFS partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30243/why-does-ubuntu-refuse-to-execute-files-from-an-ntfs-partition)
- [.exe file permission fail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18052/exe-file-permission-fail/18053#18053)

Comment: With the above command, wouldn't you need to sudo?

Comment: Did you tried to move the file to a partition that doesn't use NTFS?

Comment: i ran it from inside root....... check the '#'

Comment: @Braiam yes.... it runs

Comment: You found the answer, post an answer instead of editing your question

Answer (score 0):

This is common with ntfs mounted partitions.  You have to mount the partition with executable rights.

Try this article:  [.exe file permission fail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18052/exe-file-permission-fail/18053#18053)

Comment: I have tried, this does not work......