# Executing a C program stored on a windows drive?

Tags: permissions, executable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.exe file permission fail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18052/exe-file-permission-fail)

I wrote a simple hello world program but not stored it in Ubuntu's home directory, instead I stored it on one of the Windows drives. (I am using Ubuntu 12.04 alongside of Windows.)

When I *compiled* the program it worked just fine but **when I tried to *execute* it I got an error message "Permission denied"**.

And When I store the program in Ubuntu's home directory I can perfectly compile and execute the program. So please tell me how to overcome this problem??

Answer (score 1):

When you mount the windows partition in Ubuntu it mounts with with a noexec directive.  You could just mount that drive in your fstab if you access it from Ubuntu a lot.  You will need to run a blkid to determine what the UUID of the Windows drive is, then add a mount statement for it in your fstab.  Make sure when you get to the arguments section of the line that you don't specify noexec.

Answer (score 0):

First you should check the permissions on the file and the filesystem

```
 ls -la <filename>
```

Check if you have the appropriate rights to execute the file

Or check what the filesystem properties are for the mounted windows filesystem

```
mount
```

Paste the output here. Perhaps we can help

Answer (score 0):

You need to change to that directory and then run the program after changing permissions. You will become a super user for this purpose.

I am assuming that you can navigate to that directory in Windows where you saved that file.

Now, go to that directory and open terminal on the other side and type

```
cd
```

and drag the directory in which your .c file exists into the terminal. If your file is in Windows Desktop, the terminal will look like this:

```
cd '/media/Windows_7/Users/username/Desktop'
```

Now, let's say your file is test.c, change the permissions of the file and see whether it works using this:

```
sudo chmod 755 test.c
```

Now compile and see whether it works, if not do the same for a.out too.

If that didn't work, I guess it means that the drive permissions need to be changed.

For that the command would look something like this:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,user,fmask=0022,dmask=0000 /dev/whatever /mnt/whatever
```

where 'whatever' depends on your system.

The instructions for doing that are [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18052/exe-file-permission-fail) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-to-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/11843#11843)

If that's not what you are talking about, then you should do what mbs said.