# Linking error when trying to compile on a shared drive

Tags: mount, compiling, opencv, cmake

I am trying to compile the OpenCV library on a shared drive on my system. I was able to configure and generate makefiles successfully by using [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235288/how-to-run-an-executable-from-a-mounted-drive) settings, but when I try to compile I get the following error:

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_core.so
CMake Error: cmake_symlink_library: System Error: Operation not permitted
CMake Error: cmake_symlink_library: System Error: Operation not permitted
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.3] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How do I resolve this issue?
I think it may be an issue with the mount flags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens, because `vfat` type filesystems don't support symlinks. Mount flags won't change this situation.

I'm not familiar with CMake, but I suppose you are using some kind of rule in your makefile that is telling CMake to make a symbolic link to `lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.3`, which fails.

Comment: will it be possible if I ntfs system ? I need a file system which is compatible with windows also.

Comment: Well, try to mount your `ntfs` drive, then create a file inside and then execute the following command in your terminal: `ln -s /path-to-ntfs-drive/name-of-file /path-to-ntfs-drive/symlink-name`. If this works without an error, then I suppose you will be able to run CMake on `ntfs` drive. If you get an error, then verify that your drive is mounted via `ntfs-3g` driver (`mount` will say that `type` is `fuseblk`).

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem, because I was running on a virtual box instantiation of ubuntu (guest), but running in a shared folder to my mac (host).

Because symlinks are different on the mac, cmake failed. Moving the build directory to a ubuntu only folder (not shared with the mac) solved the problem.

Moral of the story- don't build in shared folders that cross platforms.