# Force ntfs volumes to be treated like any other by default

Tags: mount, 13.10, ntfs

I have a 20 GB NTFS volume that I was planning on using for a variety of purposes, including being readable by windows with little effort.

Unfortunately, for some reason, I cannot execute any files on the drive, even after following the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/18053/19072) (I was able to mount the volume just fine, but the error persists).

How can I fix this?

Output from mount:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)  
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)  
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)  
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)  
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)  
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)  
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)  
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)  
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)  
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)  
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)  
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)  
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)  
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)  
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)  
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=daniel)
```

Comment: So, you can't execute one file from the ntfs drive from Ubuntu, but you can execute the same file if you copy it on your home directory (`~`) in Ubuntu?

Comment: Correct, just can't be on the NTFS volume

Comment: Did you check and are you sure? If so, can you give as example what exe file has this problem?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu As sure as I can be. The example that I found is when attempting to compile clang from source, where the source and build dirs are on an NTFS volume. When I copied everything to the ext4 volume, it all worked.

Comment: None of those are NTFS, what is the mount point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure it with a GUI, install:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g ntfs-config ntfsdocs
```

And then run it from the launcher (search for ntfs).

It will add your ntfs partitions to /etc/fstab so they're mounted on startup. You can choos having read/write access too.

Comment: I think this resolved the issue, however, I was unable to find nftsdocs. What is this?

Comment: Sorry my bad, it's called ntfsdoc. Anyway I think that package it's just the manuals for the ntfs utils so it should work the same without it. Glad it helped

Answer (score 2):

The default umask for mounting NTFS does not allow execute, so I would add umask=0222 to your mount options

so based on the example in the link you followed:

```
mount -t ntfs -o fmask=0022,dmask=0000,uid=1000,gid=1000 DRIVE /media/vista
```

would become:

```
mount -t ntfs -o fmask=0022,dmask=0000,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0222 DRIVE /media/vista
```

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, from the automatically mounted nfts partition I cannot run any executable. In this case the system mount it as:

```
/dev/sdc1 on /media/romano/IOMEGA type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

I copied a executable in it and it did not work --- permission denied and it is impossible to add the "x" permission to the file.

One solution is manually mount the disk like this:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o user,relatime,umask=0022,exec /dev/sdc1 /mnt
```

(this mount the filesystem owned by root, you can use `uid=<your uid>` to mount it as you, and you can add it to `/etc/fstab` to automatically mount it).
Now it works:

```
(0)samsung-romano:/% file /mnt/trova
/mnt/trova: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically    linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, not stripped
(0)samsung-romano:/% /mnt/trova
Uso: trova [file di agenda] cosa
   file di default ./agenda
(0)samsung-romano:/% ls -lt /mnt/trova
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14756 Nov 12 20:43 /mnt/trova
```

The bad thing is that now **all** files are executable. Probably this is impossible to solve, given that NTFS does not have the "executable bit" concept. If you do `chmod -x /mnt/trova` nothing happens.

Notice that the `exec` option in the `mount` command should be the last in the list, because a lot of options (`user` for example) has a default `noexec` embedded.