# external hard drive won't let me edit files

Tags: external-hdd, file-properties

I have a 1TB HardDrive and I went to run a .jar file, it didn't work because it wasn't labeled as "[/] Allow executing file as program" and I changed the file and it reverted the file back. So how can I fix this? I tried "[Change Permissions for Enclosed Files...]" on the drive and that didn't work. I've look all over the internet and found nothing, so if anyone knows how to fix this in any way possible please tell me.

Comment: If the external drive uses a non-Linux filesystem (such as NTFS or FAT) then the issue is likely the same as this one [.exe file permission fail](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18052/exe-file-permission-fail)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `chmod` to change the rights of the file.

- Use ctrl+l to copy the folder location from Nautilus
- In the terminal, use the following code to add execution rights to your account and the group (it is easiest to paste the folder location using right-click):

  ```
  chmod u+x g+x path/to/folder/file.jar
  ```

See the Ubuntu website explaining how [file permissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions#Changing_Permissions) work and can be changed.