# With fstab, how do I automatically mount an NTFS partition with full permissions for every user?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, ntfs, fstab, automount

With the fstab file, how can I mount my /dev/sda3 NTFS partition at boot with full access by any user?

[image: Partition layout]

Comment: try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/18052/exe-file-permission-fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add this line to your `fstab`:

```
/dev/sda3 /Acer ntfs-3g defaults,user,rw,umask=000 0 0
```

Comment: I have a similar problem with Kubuntu 14.04 (dual boot with Windows7); but why do you need the ntfs-3g rather than just ntfs and is this likely to be the same with my desktop?

Comment: @WGCman You don't necessarily need to use `ntfs-3g`, `ntfs` is most likely an alias for it.